# Visual studio 2008 wont debug unit tests anymore. It used to work fine

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging

I have a project that uses Visual Studio test suite. One day I opened another instance of Visual Studio with a project that was using NUnit. I looked at and ran a few of the Unit Tests in  that project and now my Visual Studio Unit tests are no longer working. Everything just passes. I cannot hit a break point or anything. Something has totally whacked my Unit Test project. How can i fix this? The green/yellow icons are there (using resharper) but I am unable to hit break points any more. What the heck happened? Can anyone out there help me to fix this? I tried deleting the test results folder in the solutions based on another post I read but that didn't seem to work. Please help if you have any ideas.

Thanks,
~ck

Comment: Do you use the in-built test runner for MsTest or the green bubbles from resharper? When you are inside a test and press Ctrl+r, Ctrl+t, it will not debug?

Comment: I tried the Ctrl+r, Ctrl+t and that pops up a new window (Test Results) and the result says "Not Executed" with yellow triangle icon
Not Executed AddressListEntityJsonTest XyberNet.Xycor.Tests

Comment: Ah the error says a location is not trusted. How do I fix this?

Comment: You wouldn't, by any chance, be running in the Release build configuration?